# Handle Session After Close Application IOS

Tags: ios, session, cookies

I want to give this functionality to my application. When users entered login information (username and password) one time, I want to save this information and when they close the application from multitask bar ,they should be login automatically...How can i manage this?
Can you help me?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Take a look at the keychain. You can store session information in there and when the app comes back, check if there's anything in there and then validate the session information with whatever kind of servers you're using. If the session is bad or expired, simply throw up your login workflow again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

doing this in a secure fashion will require use of the Keystore.  Review the **Keychain Services Programming Guide** you'll find on the Apple Developer site for details on how to do so.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/iPhoneTasks/iPhoneTasks.html

Comment: "_SecItemAdd", referenced from:
      -[KeychainItemWrapper writeToKeychain] in KeychainItemWrapper.o
  "_SecItemCopyMatching", referenced from:
I tried to use this Keychain method but I have these errors. And before i tried to do with NSUserDefaults.? There is a way to do with NSUserDefaults too or not?